# Cocoa NSImage full view question

Tags: cocoa, nsimageview

I am trying to automatically load an image full screen after the application is launched but it looks just a little bit funky.  The outside edge of the image view can be seen - how do I eliminate that?  My code looks like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSImage *imageFromBundle = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Screen.png"];
    [image setImage:imageFromBundle];


    [image enterFullScreenMode:[window screen] withOptions:nil];
}
```

Here is the Image:
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your image view's border to none before you take it full screen. If you want, change it back when coming back from full screen, or use a separate image view for full-screen.

Also, you should name your variables more descriptively. A variable named “image” should contain a pointer to an image, not to an image view. Consider it naming `imageView` instead.